# Attach document to existing template docusign Rest API

Tags: docusignapi

I am able to send a POST request to send an existing template for signing. What I'm trying to do now is attach a PDF to the signature template. The attached PDF does not need to be signed / is not a template. It is just a PDF copy of a document as an appendix to the contract.

The request is going through ok, but I'm getting the error: `"TAB_PAGENUMBER_IS_NOT_IN_DOCUMENT",\r\n  "message": "The pagenumber specified in the tab element is not in the document that the tab refers to. Tab on Page 8 of Document 1 for Recipient 1"`

JSON:

```json
{
    "emailSubject": "Please sign this document set",
    "templateId": "xxxxxxx",
    "templateRoles": [
        {
            "email": "email@example.com",
            "roleName": "Buyer",
            "name": "Buyer Name"
        }
    ],
    "documents": [
        {
            "signerMustAcknowledge": "no_interaction",
            "order": "asc",
            "name": "MyCompany Quote",
            "includeInDownload": true,
            "documentId": "2",
            "documentBase64": "<base64string>",
            "display": "inline"
        },
    ],
    "status": "sent"
}
```

How to attach a document to an online template?

Comment: is this the entire request? you don't send any recipients? or tabs?

Answer (score 0):

The error you are seeing is because DocuSign will try to replace the document in the template with the file you are providing.

You should be able to add this additional document by using composite templates instead. https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/how-to/request-signature-composite-template-embedded/

Here is a sample:

```
{
"compositeTemplates": [
    {
        "compositeTemplateId": "1",
        "inlineTemplates": [
            {
                "recipients": {
                    "signers": [
                        {
                            "email": "email@example.com",
                            "roleName": "Buyer",
                            "name": "Buyer Name"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "sequence": "1"
            }
        ],
        "serverTemplates": [
            {
                "sequence": "1",
                "templateId": "xxxxxxx"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "compositeTemplateId": "2",
        "document": {
            "documentBase64": "<base64string>",
            "documentId": "2",
            "fileExtension": "pdf",
            "name": "MyCompany Quote"
        },
        "inlineTemplates": [
            {
                "sequence": "1"
            }
        ]
    }
],
"emailSubject": "Please sign this document set",
"status": "sent"
}
```

The first composite template is used to populate your existing template with the signers information. The second composite template is where you add the additional document you want your users to sign. You can also include additional tabs inside the inlineTemplates if they are needed in the future